# Identical Static and Global Variable in DLL libarry

Tags: c++, dll

My problem is here are three libraries, two dynamic libraries(DLL A and DLL B) and one static library C. There are some global variables and static variables defined in C, and both two DLL link with static library C. The question is when A and B are both loaded by one process, what happened to these variables? each DLL will have its own instance or they share same one.

Comment: If you have global variables defined with `static` then they have internal [linkage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Linkage) and will not be exported from the [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) where it was defined.

Comment: As for the other global variables, this breaks the ODR rule, IIRC, so basically depends.

Answer (score 0):

Unless both DLLs export that variable, nothing special happens - both DLL's have their own internal copy. If both export the variable, they still have their own copies but the program using both DLL's will need to pick.

The question is tagged C++, but this is really a Win32 answer.